# VS 11 projects backward compatibility. Converting back to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012

is there any way at all to open projects in Visual Studio 11 Beta without breaking their compatibility with Visual Studio 2010?

Maybe someone already wrote a tool that converts project files back to 2010 version?

I desperately wanna work in VS11, but all others in our team work in 2010,

Is there any tool that can convert project files back to VS2010?

Comment: I suggest that you spare a thought for the rest of your team and just stick with VS2010 for now.

Comment: It would be interesting if VS could save projects in an older format, though (Flash can do that.)  ... Not that the format would have changed significantly, the only difference might just be the version increment.

Comment: I don't know why they never do that, why with every new version of VS they break projects and solution backward compatibility.

Comment: ok. it shouldn't be very difficult to build a tool to convert projects and solutions. There's something like that, but for older ones: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70569/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Solution-File-Version-Chan

I wonder if someone already built something like that for VS11

Comment: @BoltClock What if they decide to stick to VS2010 for the next two years? The project file structure is not very complicated, I still can manage that and always revert the project version back to vs2010 manually, I thought maybe there is already a tool for that

Answer (score 1):

If your team is using VS2010 SP1 then you are probably OK already. Visual Studio supports round tripping of solutions and projects between versions now so that you can open a project in VS11, make changes, and then open it in VS2010 without breaking anything.

More information can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx  and the [compatibility list is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747%28VS.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Agzam That's probably due to MVC2 not being supported out of the box in VS11.  Only MVC3 and MVC4 are.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work: http://vsprojectconverter.codeplex.com ?